# Cannot insert None using python and mysql in datetime field

Tags: python, mysql, datetime, insert, null

Consider the following code:
The first query does not work while the second does.
The problem is... since I need to compose a query beforehand via a function this function returns a variable as 'val'. So I need to get the first query to work. The second query is only added by example to show what happens when the content of 'val' is used literally.
Please help!
So, I want to insert a datetime but 'None' is also to be accepted. The current error is:

```
    query = query % db.literal(args)
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Now the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import MySQLdb as mdb

def prepare():
# Assume a database named 'db_test'
    conn = mdb.connect(host   = 'localhost', \
                       user   = 'test',      \
                       passwd = 'test',      \
                       db     = 'db_test')

    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TBL_TEST")
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE TBL_TEST(Moo1 DATETIME, Moo2 DATETIME)")

    return cur

if __name__ == '__main__':
    qry = "INSERT INTO TBL_TEST (Moo1, Moo2) VALUES (%s, %s)"
    val = "('2012-04-03 08:40:39', None)"

    cur = prepare()
    cur.execute(qry, val) # NOK
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO TBL_TEST (Moo1, Moo2) VALUES (%s, %s)", ('2012-04-03 08:40:39', None)) # OK
```

Trust me - I searched the world but without any success..
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Your `val` is a string, it should be a tuple:

```
val = ('2012-04-03 08:40:39', None)
```

Comment: This worked for the example. The 'real' code is as follows (just a small part):
    val = (parseRow(cursor1),)
This makes val a tuple (checked with 'print type(val)')
cursor2.execute(qry, val)
gives:    
        query = query % db.literal(args)
    TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Does parseRow return a single value? Then you want `val = (parseRow(cursor1), None)`.

Comment: Parserow returns a string type which is dynamically composed. Therefore, I cannot put 'None' behind it.
I tried 'val = (parseRow(cursor1),)' to enforce a tuple but with no luck

Comment: More information:
    def parseRow(cur):
        values = []
        for field in cur.fetchone():
            if (field):
                values.append(field.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
            else:
                values.append(str(field))
        return values

'print var' leads to:

['2012-04-03 08:40:39', 'None']

How can I get parseRow to return something I can execute() ?

Comment: To convert it to tuple, call `tuple`: `val = tuple(parseRow(cursor1))`